# How to disable Clock Resolution selection prompt?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

Each time I do `org-clock-in` the following prompt appears:

```
Select a Clock Resolution Command:

i/q      Ignore this question; the same as keeping all the idle time.

k/K      Keep X minutes of the idle time (default is all).  If this
         amount is less than the default, you will be clocked out
         that many minutes after the time that idling began, and then
         clocked back in at the present time.

t/T      Like `k', but will ask you to specify a time (when you got
         distracted away), instead of a number of minutes.

g/G      Indicate that you \"got back\" X minutes ago.  This is quite
         different from `k': it clocks you out from the beginning of
         the idle period and clock you back in X minutes ago.

s/S      Subtract the idle time from the current clock.  This is the
         same as keeping 0 minutes.

C        Cancel the open timer altogether.  It will be as though you
         never clocked in.

j/J      Jump to the current clock, to make manual adjustments.

For all these options, using uppercase makes your final state
to be CLOCKED OUT.
```

So each time, I have to press q to ignore it. How could I disable this prompt?

Comment: You don't want to disable the prompt, you want to assign the idle time to a clock (or throw it away). Then Org mode will stop nagging you. See [Resolving idle time and continuous clocking](https://orgmode.org/manual/Resolving-idle-time.html).

Comment: Great advice, thank you @NickD!